# Declaring a block inside <default> giving error in other refernce node

Tags: layout, blocks, local.xml

I am trying to override `inchoo social connect plugin`, but I am facing some kind of layout issue, unable to resolve

my

> local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="youamaajaxlogin">
            <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" as='test'>
                <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/google_button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button" />
                <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/facebook_button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_facebook_login_button" />
                <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/twitter_button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_twitter_login_button" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>  

    <customer_account_login>
        <reference name="customer_form_login">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>diboltplus/customer/form/login.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
            <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login">
                <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/google_button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button" />
                <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/facebook_button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_facebook_login_button" />
                <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/twitter_button" name="inchoo_socialconnect_twitter_login_button" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
</layout>
```

The `<default>` node having the layout block for popup login,I have included a block `inchoo_socialconnect_login`, and able to call it from my template file and its working fine as expected, but `<customer_account_login>` node when I am including the same block `inchoo_socialconnect_login` inside it and trying it to call from `diboltplus/customer/form/login.phtml`, the block is not visible in template, but if I comment my default node code, than I am able to call block `inchoo_socialconnect_login` from the template.

I am doing something wrong here?

I have tried giving alias name too , but its not working.

Any help !

[image: Commenting Default]

[image: When both are present]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of things that makes confusion here. Let me explore those below.

1. You have included your block `inchoo_socialconnect_login` inside `<default />` layout update handle. This means you have that block available in almost every page. I am sure this block is available in  customer account page too. So why are you trying to re-declare same block again in your customer account page ?
2. You are using same names for your button blocks in both `default` and `customer_account_login` layout update handles. This is what makes problem here. You should uniquely differentiate socialconnect_login block which you included via `default` layout update handle and via `customer_account_login`. So try this.

   ```
   <customer_account_login>
   <reference name="customer_form_login">
       <action method="setTemplate">
           <template>diboltplus/customer/form/login.phtml</template>
       </action>
       <block type="persistent/form_remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="persistent/remember_me.phtml" />
       <block type="core/template" name="persistent.remember.me.tooltip" template="persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml" />
       <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/login" name="customer.inchoo_socialconnect_login" as="sc_login">
           <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/google_button" name="customer.inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button" as="inchoo_socialconnect_google_login_button" />
           <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/facebook_button" name="customer.inchoo_socialconnect_facebook_login_button" as="inchoo_socialconnect_facebook_login_button" />
           <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/twitter_button" name="customer.inchoo_socialconnect_twitter_login_button" as="inchoo_socialconnect_twitter_login_button" />
       </block>
   </reference>
   </customer_account_login>
   ```

Now inside the template `diboltplus/customer/form/login.phtml`, call your socialconnect_login block like this :

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sc_login') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , I have got the issue its because of block file , when you made two time call it checks if a instance is present it doesnot render again ! Thanks anyways bro :)

Comment: @n01ze if you declare those button block as I have shown in my point-2 sections, you will get two unique blocks. one from `default` handle and one from `customer_account_login` handle. so both of them will render. I dont know what you are trying to achieve. If you resolve this issue, then please put an answer and accept it or if my answer helped you, you can accept mine

Comment: see I already have used alias as you mentioned  <block type="inchoo_socialconnect/login" name="inchoo_socialconnect_login" as='test'> still not working

Comment: @n01ze read my answer twice. I clearly mentioned that, problem resides in the name not in alias. my block is `<block type="inchoo_socialconnect/login" name="customer.inchoo_socialconnect_login" as="sc_login">`. see the name is `customer.inchoo_socialconnect_login` which is differnt than `inchoo_socialconnect_login`

Comment: Yes bro , tried that option too

Comment: @n01ze make sure you clear your cache after every changes made

Comment: It is disable and I clear it always , anyways its working now

Comment: @n01ze great. then put your finding as an answer and accept it or accept mine if it helped you. Please don't leave question as it is.

Comment: Sure bro , by evening ill put it up